# Python invert numbers in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

What would be the most efficient way of inverting (i.e. multiplying with -1) the integers in the strings in a list using python?

Example input:

```
['-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 9 -10 11',' -17 18 19 20 -21 22 -23 ',' -36 -37 -38 39 40 41 42 -43 44 ']
```

Desired output:

```
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -9 10 -11', '17 -18 -19 -20 21 -22 23', '36 37 38 -39 -40 -41 -42 43 -44']
```

Comment: What do you mean "invert"? What is the output you expect here?

Comment: Need more precise info about what you want the output to look like.  Also need to know what approach you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really have a list of strings with numbers written in the string? or do you have a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, I have list of strings with numbers written in the string.I am reading these numbers from separate files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using simple list comprehensions

```
>>> lst = ['-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 9 -10 11',' -17 18 19 20 -21 22 -23 ',' -36 -37 -38 39 40 41 42 -43 44 ']
>>> [' '.join(map(lambda x: str(-int(x)), s.split())) for s in lst]
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -9 10 -11', '17 -18 -19 -20 21 -22 23', '36 37 38 -39 -40 -41 -42 43 -44']
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want. Hopefully the variable and function names make it relatively clear what's going on.

```
list_of_strings = ['-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 9 -10 11',' -17 18 19 20 -21 22 -23 ',' -36 -37 -38 39 40 41 42 -43 44 ']

def process(string_of_ints):
    return ' '.join( str(-int(each_word)) for each_word in string_of_ints.split() )

result = [ process(each_string) for each_string in list_of_strings ]
print(result)
```

It can be collapsed into one line at the cost of some clarity:

```
result = [ ' '.join( str(-int(each_word)) for each_word in each_string.split() ) for each_string in list_of_strings ]
```

(NB: "invert" is really a potentially misleading word - in mathematics, when used unqualified, the most common interpretation means do 1/x,  not -x; in computing it might mean any one of a number of different things, including reversing the order of a sequence).

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding, will be more precise the next time

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach then what has been posted so far

```
l=['-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 9 -10 11',' -17 18 19 20 -21 22 -23 ',' -36 -37 -38 39 40 41 42 -43 44 ']

for i in xrange(len(l)):
    tmp=[]
    for s in l[i].split():
        tmp.append(str(-int(s)))
    l[i]=' '.join(tmp)
print l

['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -9 10 -11', '17 -18 -19 -20 21 -22 23', '36 37 38 -39 -40 -41 -42 43 -44']
```